# Netbeans Chrome Extensions Source Code

Tags: google-chrome, netbeans, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, netbeans-plugins

Is **Netbeans Chrome Extensions** Open Source ?
If yes then , where to find netbeans chrome extensions source code ?

Comment: In general, in reply to "Where to find the source code of Chrome extension X", I would say, use the [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) (provided that the extension is installed from the Chrome Web Store or some other online source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs on **[NetBeans Sources](https://netbeans.org/community/sources/hg.html)**:

> All the souce code made available on netbeans.org is provided to you under the terms and conditions of Common Development and Distribution License (CDDL) v1.0 and the GNU General Public License (GPL) v2.

The source code for the **Netbeans Chrome Extension** is indeed part of the sources, so the same licenses apply.

To access the sources, you have the following options:

1. Download an archived snapshot (ZIP) from the **[downloads page](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)**.
2. **[Browse the sources](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/)** online. E.g.:
   a. The Chrome Extension code can be found **[here](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/45b2ebbff7bc/extbrowser.chrome/plugins/chrome)**.
   b. The Java classes that implement the integreation can be found **[there](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/45b2ebbff7bc/extbrowser.chrome/src/org/netbeans/modules/extbrowser/chrome)**.
3. Using Mercurial to work with **[NetBeans Sources in the IDE](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HgNetBeansSources)**.